# Сортировка товара в админке по атрибутам - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Много где спрашивал, все молчат.
Можно ли сортировать товары в админке в меню "Все товары" по атрибуту?
Товаров много и хочется их сортировать при редактировании по определенному атрибуту.
А плагином таких нет, может есть решение?

[Вот нашел плагин](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/admin-category-filter/) только сортировки по дате публикации, и то, что-то он не заработал...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, плагин **Admin Columns** - этот плагин управляет стандартными колонками или создает новые.